# Why is drag and drop only working in ISE, do I miss an assembly? (Windows forms in powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have a larger powershell application which is using drag & drop to process quotes . All is working fine, but only in ISE. When I'm using the script by shortcut on the desktop (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -file "D:\Powershell\test\dragndrop.ps1") drag and drop is not working.

The error message is:

**Type [System.Windows.DragDropEffects] not found**

My powershell version:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145                                                                                                                                                                                        
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                              
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                              
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145                                                                                                                                                                                       
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                      
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                  
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                  
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Running on Windows 10 64 bit, 1903

This is the form I'm using with the application. It's modified so you can copy & paste the script for testing without any modification.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    $form.Visible = $false
    [void]$form.SuspendLayout()
    $form.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,380) 
    $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
    $form.MaximizeBox = $false
    $form.MinimizeBox = $false
    $form.HelpButton  = $true

    $CTRL_TabCtrl = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
    $CTRL_TabCtrl.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(5,5)
    $CTRL_TabCtrl.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(310,370)
    [void]$form.Controls.Add($CTRL_TabCtrl)

    $CTRL_Tab1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
    $CTRL_Tab1.AutoSize = $true
    $CTRL_Tab1.Text = 'Chose Quote'
    $CTRL_Tab1.TabIndex = 1
    [void]$CTRL_TabCtrl.Controls.Add($CTRL_Tab1)

    $CTRL_Tab2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
    $CTRL_Tab2.AutoSize = $true
    $CTRL_Tab2.Text = 'Settings'
    $CTRL_Tab2.TabIndex = 2
    [void]$CTRL_TabCtrl.Controls.Add($CTRL_Tab2)

    $CTRL_label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $CTRL_label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10) 
    $CTRL_label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
    $CTRL_label1.Text = 'Please select quote (PDF or Excel):'
    $CTRL_label1.Name = 'Label1'
    $CTRL_label1.Add_MouseHover( $showHelp )
    [void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_label1) 

    $CTRL_PathQuote = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $CTRL_PathQuote.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30) 
    $CTRL_PathQuote.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(275,20) 
    $CTRL_PathQuote.MaxLength = 250
    $CTRL_PathQuote.Name = 'PathQuote'
    $CTRL_PathQuote.Add_MouseHover( $showHelp )
    [void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_PathQuote) 

    $CTRL_UploadButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CTRL_UploadButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,60)
    $CTRL_UploadButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
    $CTRL_UploadButton.Text = 'Select File...'
    $CTRL_UploadButton.Name = 'UploadButton'
    $CTRL_UploadButton.Add_MouseHover( $showHelp )
    #$CTRL_UploadButton.Add_Click( { Get-FileName-Dialog -textBox $CTRL_PathQuote } )
    [void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_UploadButton)

    $CTRL_label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $CTRL_label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,100) 
    $CTRL_label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
    $CTRL_label3.Text = 'Or drop quote here: (drag && drop):'
    $CTRL_label3.Name = 'Label3'
    $CTRL_label3.Add_MouseHover( $showHelp )
    [void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_label3) 

    $CTRL_PictureBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    $CTRL_PictureBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
    $CTRL_PictureBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,174)
    $CTRL_PictureBox.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::FixedSingle
    $CTRL_PictureBox.AllowDrop = $true

    $CTRL_PictureBox.Add_DragOver({
        if ($_.Data.GetDataPresent([System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
            foreach ($filename in $_.Data.GetData([System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
                if( @( '.pdf', '.xlsx').Contains( [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename).ToLower() ) ) {
                    $_.Effect = [System.Windows.DragDropEffects]::Copy
                    $CTRL_PictureBox.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::DarkGray
                }
                else {
                    $_.Effect = [System.Windows.DragDropEffects]::None
                    $CTRL_PictureBox.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Transparent
                }
                break #only first file
            }
        }
    })

    $CTRL_PictureBox.Add_DragDrop({
        if ($_.Data.GetDataPresent([System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
            foreach ($filename in $_.Data.GetData([System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
                if( @( '.pdf', '.xlsx').Contains( [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename).ToLower() ) ) {
                    $_.Effect = [System.Windows.DragDropEffects]::All
                    $CTRL_PathQuote.Text   = $filename
                }
                else {
                    $_.Effect = [System.Windows.DragDropEffects]::None
                }
                break #only first file
            }
        }
    })

    [void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_PictureBox)

    $CTRL_OKButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CTRL_OKButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(70,310)
    $CTRL_OKButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CTRL_OKButton1.Text = 'Start'
    $CTRL_OKButton1.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.AcceptButton = $CTRL_OKButton1
    [void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_OKButton1)
    $CTRL_OKButton1.Enabled = $false

    $CTRL_CancelButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CTRL_CancelButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,310)
    $CTRL_CancelButton1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CTRL_CancelButton1.Text = 'Abbrechen'
    $CTRL_CancelButton1.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
    $form.CancelButton = $CTRL_CancelButton1
    [void]$CTRL_Tab1.Controls.Add($CTRL_CancelButton1)



    $scriptBlock_OkButton1        = {   $CTRL_PathQuote.Text.Trim().Length -gt 0 -and (Test-Path -Path $CTRL_PathQuote.Text -PathType leaf) }

    $scriptBlock_PathQuoteChanged = {
                                        $CTRL_OKButton1.Enabled = & $scriptBlock_OkButton1; 
                                        $CTRL_PictureBox.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Transparent
                                        if( !$CTRL_OKButton1.Enabled ) {
                                            $CTRL_PictureBox.Image = $dragnDropImg
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $CTRL_PictureBox.Image = $dragnDropOkImg
                                        }
                                    }


    $CTRL_OKButton1.Enabled = & $scriptBlock_OkButton1 

    [void]$CTRL_PathQuote.Add_TextChanged( { & $scriptBlock_PathQuoteChanged } )
    [void]$CTRL_PictureBox.Add_DragLeave( { & $scriptBlock_PathQuoteChanged } )

    [void]$form.ResumeLayout()

    $userInput = $form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `[System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]` instead of `[System.Windows.DragDropEffects]` in all the places you are using it..